# JavaScript Popups doesn't close

Tags: javascript, popup

I am doing a careers page for a website, vacancies get listed on the page and when you click on it the job description pops up, the thing is i want it to close when you click elsewhere i got the first item to do so but the rest will not.

```
<div class="joblisting">

    <a href="#" class="contact" id="job_id">
        <div class="messagepop pop"  id="menucontainer">
            job_description
        </div>
        <p>click to read description...</p>
    </a>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ2BS/2/ : here it is on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You have two elements with the same id. Use a class instead.

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 

    if($('.messagepop').is(":visible")) {
        $('.messagepop').hide()
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/philwills/ZZ2BS/4/

Answer (score 0):

Hide your popup element on click anywhere and use `stopPropagation()` to exclude element itself.

```
var popup = documrnt.getElementById("popup_id");

document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    popup.style.display = "none"
}, false);

popup.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```